# how to move touch from one toggle button from another?

Tags: android

Here is the code of Android XML. In this XML, 9 toggle buttons are presented in a 3*3 matrix.

Now i want to connect one toggle button to another toggle button. Is it performed by OnTouchListner? If yes, then how?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#004D40" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/fs"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ft"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fs"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fs"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/sf"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ff"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ss"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sf"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ft"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/st"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ft"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ss"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tf"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sf"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sf"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ts"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ss"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tf"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tt"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/st"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ts"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/ff"
        style="@style/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fs"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_toggle_bg" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sf"
        android:text="TextVie" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click and hold one toggle button to others then you have to manage **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** with X, Y coordinate in OnTouchListener.

For Pattern lock you can use library like :
https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/PatternLock

Comment: i already check this
my please see this code

fs.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
     return true;
    else
    return false;
   }
  });